# React Native IllegalViewOperationException: StackOverflowException Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

**CONFIGURATION**

I have this setup:

**RootNavigation**

```
import React from "react";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import EventScreen from "../screens/EventScreen";
import BottomTab from "./BottomTab";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function RootNavigator() {

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="BottomTab"
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false
            }}
        >
            <Stack.Screen name="Event" >
                {(props) => <EventScreen {...props} />}
            </Stack.Screen>
            <Stack.Screen name="BottomTab" >
                {(props) => <BottomTab {...props} />}
            </Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

**BottomTab**

```
export const BottomTabContext = createContext();

export default function BottomTab({ navigation }) {

  const rootNavigation = navigation;
  return (
    <BottomTabContext.Provider value={{ rootNavigation }}>

     <Tab.Navigator >
      <Tab.Screen
          name="HomeNavigator"

          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
              if (focused)
                return (
                  <View
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
                      borderRadius: 20,
                      width: "80%",
                      height: "60%",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      justifyContent: "center",
                    }}
                  >
                    <Ant name="home" color={"white"} size={28} />
                  </View>
                );
              return <Ant name="home" color={Colors.primary} size={28} />;
            },
          }}
        >
          {(props) => <HomeScreen {...props} />}
        </Tab.Screen>
       ....Other screens...
     </Tab.Navigator>
    </BottomTabContext.Provider>

  );
```

**EVENT SCREEN**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, Image, ScrollView, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Linking } from "react-native"
import "@react-native-firebase/functions"

import QRCode from '../components/QrCode';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

import LinearGradient from "react-native-linear-gradient";

import { AuthContext } from "../App";

import Ant from "react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign";
import Fea from "react-native-vector-icons/Feather";
import Awe from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";

import GradientText from "../components/GradientText";
import CustomModal from '../components/CustomModal';

import Colors from "../utils/Colors";
import truncate from "../utils/Utils";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("screen");

import { addSavedEvents, removeSavedEvents, getSavedEvents, buyTicket, getEventSubscriptions } from "../api/api";

export default App = (props) => {

    const [isAlreadySold, setSold] = React.useState(false);
    const [isSaved, setIsSaved] = React.useState(false);
    const [qrValue, setQrValue] = React.useState("0");
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = React.useState(false);
    const [buySource, setBuySource] = React.useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

    const navigation = props.navigation;
    const event = props.route.params.event;

    const { token, user } = useContext(AuthContext);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = async () => {
            getSavedEvents(token).then(response => {
                if (response.data.success == "1") {
                    response.data.message.saved_events.forEach(savedEvent => {
                        if (savedEvent.event_id == event.event_id) setIsSaved(true);
                    });
                }
                else setIsSaved(false)
            })

            getEventSubscriptions(token, event.event_id).then(response => {
                if (response.data.success == "1") {
                    let subscription = response.data.message.subscribed.subscription.slice().reverse()
                    subscription.forEach(sub => {
                        if (sub.sub_user == user.id && sub.sub_event == event.event_id && !isAlreadySold) {
                            setSold(true);
                            setQrValue(sub.sub_keypass + "&" + event.event_id)
                        }
                    })
                }
                setLoading(false);
            })
        };

        unsubscribe();
    }, []);



    const toogleSaved = async () => {

        if (!isSaved) {
            addSavedEvents(token, event.event_id).then(() => {
                setIsSaved(true);
            })
            //functions.httpsCallable("addSavedEvent")({"eventId": eventId, "userId": auth().currentUser.uid});
        }
        else {
            removeSavedEvents(token, event.event_id).then(() => {
                setIsSaved(false);
            })
            //functions.httpsCallable("deleteSavedEvent")({"eventId": eventId, "userId": auth().currentUser.uid});
        }
    }


    const buy = async () => {
        buyTicket(token, event.event_id).then((response) => {
            if (response.data.success == "1") {
                //Linking.openURL(response.data.message.payment_link);
                if (response.data.message.need_payment == 1) {
                    setBuySource(response.data.message.payment_link);
                    setModalVisible(true)
                }
                else {
                    getEventSubscriptions(token, event.event_id).then(response => {
                        if (response.data.success == "1") {
                            let subscription = response.data.message.subscribed.subscription.slice().reverse()
                            subscription.forEach(sub => {
                                if (sub.sub_user == user.id && sub.sub_event == event.event_id && !isAlreadySold) {
                                    setSold(true);
                                    setQrValue(sub.sub_keypass + "&" + event.event_id)
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }

    if (loading) return (<View></View>)

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: "white", flex: 1, alignItems: "center" }}>
            <View style={{
                width: width,
                paddingLeft: 15
            }}
            >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { if (navigation.canGoBack()) { navigation.goBack() } }}>
                    <Ant name="arrowleft" size={27} color={Colors.primary} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            {isAlreadySold &&
                <View style={styles.qrContainer}>

                    <QRCode
                        value={qrValue}
                        size={150}
                        enableLinearGradient
                        linearGradient={[Colors.primary, "black"]}
                    />
                </View>
            }
            <ScrollView
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                style={{
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "100%",
                }}
                contentContainerStyle={{
                    alignItems: "center",
                    height: "100%"
                }}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets
            >
                <View
                    style={{
                        borderRadius: 20,
                        width: width * 0.7,
                        height: width * 0.7,
                    }}
                >
                    <ImageBackground source={{ uri: event.event_cover_src }} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", overflow: "hidden", borderRadius: 20 }} resizeMode="stretch" >
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: "column-reverse", flex: 1, alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
                            <LinearGradient
                                colors={["rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)", "#7ca8ff", Colors.primary]}
                                start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                                end={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
                                style={{ width: "100%", height: "30%" }}
                            >
                                <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "flex-end", width: "100%", height: "100%", padding: 15 }}>
                                    <Text style={{ color: "white", fontFamily: "college", fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: (100) / (Math.sqrt(event.event_name.length)) }}>{truncate(event.event_name)}</Text>
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toogleSaved(1)}>
                                        <Awe name={isSaved ? "bookmark" : "bookmark-o"} size={25} color="white" />
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                            </LinearGradient>
                        </View>
                    </ImageBackground>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", width: width, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "flex-start", paddingLeft: 20, marginTop: 5, padding: 2 }}>
                        <Fea name="map-pin" size={22} color={Colors.primary} />
                        <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>{event.event_address}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", width: width, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "flex-start", paddingLeft: 20, marginTop: 5, padding: 2 }}>
                        <Ant name="calendar" size={22} color={Colors.primary} />
                        <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>{event.event_date}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", width: width, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "flex-start", paddingLeft: 20, marginTop: 5, padding: 2 }}>
                        <Ant name="infocirlceo" size={22} color={Colors.primary} />
                        <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>Solo {event.event_price}€ {event.need_payment == "0" ? "Pagamento il loco" : ""}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={{ width, padding: 5, paddingLeft: 15, paddingTop: 20 }}>
                    <GradientText style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 21, marginBottom: 5, fontFamily: "college" }}>INFORMAZIONI</GradientText>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 17 }}>{event.event_description}</Text>
                </View>

            </ScrollView>
            {!isAlreadySold &&
                <View
                    style={styles.bookContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: 15, padding: 10 }} onPress={buy}>
                        <Text style={{ color: Colors.primary, fontWeight: "600", fontSize: 25, fontFamily: "college" }}>PRENOTA</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

            }
            <CustomModal
                isVisible={modalVisible}
                message=""

            >
                <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "flex-end", width: "100%" }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: 20, padding: 5, width: 40, height: 40, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }} onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
                        <Text style={{ color: Colors.primary, fontWeight: "900", fontSize: 22 }}>X</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                {buySource.length > 1 && <WebView
                    source={{ uri: buySource }}
                    style={{
                        marginTop: 20,
                        maxHeight: height,
                        width: 320,
                        flex: 1
                    }}
                />}

            </CustomModal>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );


}
```

**Expected Behaviour**
When I go back from Event Screen I end up to Home Screen

**Problem**
On IOS there's no problems, it works fine.

On Android when I go Back it crashes.
The error is:

*com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: StackOverflowException*

**Debug Logs**

```
I/m.unifraternit: Background concurrent copying GC freed 61530(2508KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 5972KB/11MB, paused 627us total 149.136ms
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I/m.unifraternit: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 36271(1282KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(80KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 6327KB/12MB, paused 1.667ms total 125.046ms
E/unknown:ReactNative: Unable to handle Exception - catalystInstanceVariableExists: true - isCatalystInstanceAlive: false - hasExceptionHandler: false
    com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: StackOverflowException
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:754)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4301)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22353)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1833)
        at com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollView.draw(ReactScrollView.java:530)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.drawChild(ReactViewGroup.java:772)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4301)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:744)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22353)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.drawChild(ReactViewGroup.java:772)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4301)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:744)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22353)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4301)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1277)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStack.performDraw(ScreenStack.kt:304)
        at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStack.access$performDraw(ScreenStack.kt:14)
        at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStack$DrawingOp.draw(ScreenStack.kt:325)
        at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStack.drawAndRelease(ScreenStack.kt:278)
        at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStack.dispatchDraw(ScreenStack.kt:295)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.drawChild(ReactViewGroup.java:772)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:744)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
E/unknown:ReactNative:     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:559)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:565)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4101)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3828)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3099)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at org.reactnative.maskedview.RNCMaskedView.updateBitmapMask(RNCMaskedView.java:58)
        at org.reactnative.maskedview.RNCMaskedView.dispatchDraw(RNCMaskedView.java:33)
        at android.view.View.buildDrawingCacheImpl(View.java:21617)
        at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:21483)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22073)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.drawChild(ReactViewGroup.java:772)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4301)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:744)
            ... 94 more
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.unifraternity, PID: 25559
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: StackOverflowException
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.handleException(ReactContext.java:426)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:754)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4301)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22353)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1833)
        at com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollView.draw(ReactScrollView.java:530)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.drawChild(ReactViewGroup.java:772)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4301)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:744)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22353)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.drawChild(ReactViewGroup.java:772)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4301)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:744)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22353)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4301)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1277)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStack.performDraw(ScreenStack.kt:304)
        at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStack.access$performDraw(ScreenStack.kt:14)
        at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStack$DrawingOp.draw(ScreenStack.kt:325)
        at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStack.drawAndRelease(ScreenStack.kt:278)
        at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStack.dispatchDraw(ScreenStack.kt:295)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.drawChild(ReactViewGroup.java:772)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:744)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:559)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:565)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4101)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3828)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3099)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: StackOverflowException
            ... 95 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at org.reactnative.maskedview.RNCMaskedView.updateBitmapMask(RNCMaskedView.java:58)
        at org.reactnative.maskedview.RNCMaskedView.dispatchDraw(RNCMaskedView.java:33)
        at android.view.View.buildDrawingCacheImpl(View.java:21617)
        at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:21483)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22073)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.drawChild(ReactViewGroup.java:772)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4301)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:744)
            ... 94 more
```

**ANY SOLUTION?**

Comment: It crashes only when I go back from EventScreen

Comment: Same thing happens to me

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am facing this on android app

Answer (score 2):

In my case I found that using GradientText on the nav screen caused this issue.

If I use createStackNavigator from @react-navigation/stack instead of createNativeStackNavigator from @react-navigation/native-stack issue does not exist. So this could be a possible solution.

Looks like MaskedView from '@react-native-community/masked-view' which is used in GradientText is the reason here. Native stack does not work ok with it on Android.

Comment: thanks for posting. ran into the exact problem and this lead us to identity the issue.